# Setup Wicket application/JBoss Server to use my domain URL

Tags: jboss, dns, wicket

I just purchased a domain Url from Google Domains and I'd like to have my localhost project (Wicket app. deployed on Jboss server) to use my new domain (example.com). I have looked online for a process on doing this, but seeing as this is a very specific instance, I cannot find the proper documentation. I have made my ip addr. static, added my external IP addr. to the Google Domain website (I think this registers my domain to my ip?), and I've edited the Window's Host file to point 127.0.0.1 to example.com. What am I missing here? Is there a configuration in my wicket project's web.xml or maybe a configuration in my JBoss server? I'm using Wicket 7.0.0 (latest) and JBoss 7.0. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an network expert, but you could check if you are receiving any traffic on your JBOSS server port without application deployed, just to make sure that your firewall or any sort of Antivirus is blocking incoming traffic or not.

Comment: This is not the case. I just need the process of linking my domain name to my localhost application. I'm not sure if it's a JBoss config, or Wicket config